# Getting remote URL string without UI freezes?

Tags: c#

I have a method as below for getting remote URL string.

```
public string FnGetURLContent(string _QsURL)
        { 
            string _Return = "";

            try
            {    
                HttpWebRequest _HttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_QsURL);
                _HttpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)";

                _HttpWebRequest.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4;
                _HttpWebRequest.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 4;

                _HttpWebRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                HttpWebResponse _HttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)_HttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

                Stream receiveStream = _HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

                encoding format. 
                StreamReader _StreamReader = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

                _Return = _StreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                _HttpWebResponse.Close();
                _StreamReader.Close();

            }
            catch (WebException _WebException)
            {
                _Return = "";
            }

            return _Return;

        }
```

When method runs, form UIs freezes until method finishes to process.
How can i improve codes?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm not usually too put off by naming conventions, but wow!  This is tough code to read.

Comment: How can your browser freeze by server-side code?

Comment: Run the code to get the remote url string in a separate thread to your UI one.

Answer (score 2):

You can "improve codes" by using an asynchronous [background worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). See the [class here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Comment: How would you know he is using a technology/platform that allows the usage ob background workers?

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can use _HttpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync() and handle response data on a separate thread after it is received.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. You can do this:

1. You can use the key-words: async and await, which came with .net 4.5 ([Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/hh156513.aspx))
2. You can use a Background-Worker ([Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx))
3. You can start a new Thread ([Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx))

There are many more ways to achieve your goal

Answer (score 0):

This is the life's purpose of node.js.  The key is to make this async.  For your case, see the msdn docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx).